# Select onchange doesnt work

Tags: html-framework-7

Anyone else has this problem that select doesn't work good in framework7?

After building apk file select sometimes needs to be changed twice to take effect.

What can cause it ? I removed all external files, and it's sill not working as it should.

```
<select id="random-select">
                            <option id="1">1</option>
                            <option id="2">2</option>
                            <option id="3">3</option>
                            <option id="4">4</option>
                            <option id="5">5</option>
                            <option id="6">6</option>
                        </select>

    $('#random-select').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

Code is simple as that for select.
It's in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with framework7,Actually webkit fast-click is not supported.I faced the same issue and resolved the problem by adding a simple class to select element class="no-fastclick",It will work properly.
Another way is to add "fastclick:false" in app init.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#random-select').change(function()
 {
    alert($(this).val());
    
  });
    
  
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="random-select"  name="selectbox" >
                            <option id="1">1</option>
                            <option id="2">2</option>
                            <option id="3">3</option>
                            <option id="4">4</option>
                            <option id="5">5</option>
                            <option id="6">6</option>
                        </select>
```