# Select onchange event does not works on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I have this javascript code which is within Framework7 used for a phonegap application. I want the values to change in table as soon as the option is selected; this does not work when a value is selected for the 1st time but works flawlessly when selected second time.

```
$('#mySelect931').on('change', function (e) {

  var value = document.getElementById("mySelect931").value;
      //myApp.alert(value);

      if(value == 'M4'){
            var a = 'M4'; //value of d
            var b = '14'; // value of b to 125
            var c = '-'; //value of b to 200
            var d = '-'; // value of b over 200
            var e = '2.8'; // value of k
            var f = '7.66'; // value of e
            var g = '7'; // value of s
        }
});
```

Here's html code.

```
<select id="mySelect931" style='background-color: #e3e3e3; color: black;'>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Value</option>
    <option value="M4">M4</option>
    <option value="M5">M5</option>
    <option value="M6">M6</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried running your code and it works perfectly fine, even with framework7 loaded. So, atleast we know that framework7 isn't the real issue here. I think you are somehow attaching another event listener on the element `#mySelect931`. You could try to remove all event listeners on your element my using `$('#mySelect931').off();` and figure out if thats the root cause.

Please check the snippet:

```js
    // code works even without the below line
    $('#mySelect931').off();  // remove all event listeners for this element
    $('#mySelect931').on('change', function (e) {
        var value = document.getElementById("mySelect931").value;
        alert('selected Value: ' + value);
        if(value == 'M4'){
            var a = 'M4'; //value of d
            var b = '14'; // value of b to 125
            var c = '-'; //value of b to 200
            var d = '-'; // value of b over 200
            var e = '2.8'; // value of k
            var f = '7.66'; // value of e
            var g = '7'; // value of s
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.5.4/js/framework7.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect931" style='background-color: #e3e3e3; color: black;'>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Value</option>
    <option value="M4">M4</option>
    <option value="M5">M5</option>
    <option value="M6">M6</option>
</select>
```

Another *dirty hack* could be, is to trigger the `change` event yourself. i.e. `$('#mySelect931').trigger('change');`
However, it is not the correct way to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

TRY WITH BELOW CODE

```
HTML
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select id="mySelect931" style='background-color: #e3e3e3; color: black;'>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Value</option>
    <option value="M4">M4</option>
    <option value="M5">M5</option>
    <option value="M6">M6</option>
</select>

JQUERY
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#mySelect931').change(function(){
        alert(jQuery(this).val());
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value **as soon as the value is selected**, you will need to use `onclick`. `onchange` only works when the new selected value is different than the actual selected (your code works perfectly as I tried).

Comment: onclick does not work; onchange is the right method however it requires me the select the option twice for the first time. The error is mainly when using this in Framework7

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520765/select-onchange-doesnt-work. I cannot be of more help.

Comment: try $('#mySelect931').trigger('change'); after select onchange.